# Перестали запускаться проекты в Eclipse после добавления -vm

Tags: java, eclipse

Все началось с того, что при запуске `Eclipse` вылезала следующая ошибка:

```
Eclipse - Incompatible JVM. Version 1.8.0_261 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. 
Version: 11 or greater is required
```

Поискал в интернете - прочитал, что надо в `eclipse.ini` добавить следующие строчки:

```
-vm
C:\...\jdk-15.0.1\bin\javaw.exe
```

Заработало, запустился `Eclipse`, но при запуске проекта вылезает следующая ошибка:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching JMain".
org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugMode
```

А так же почему-то в консоли появилась надпись `Android`:

[image: изображение]

хотя проект - `Desktop-приложение`

Стуктура проекта:

```
> Project
  > JRE System Library [JavaSE - 1.8]
  > src
    > (default package)
       > JMain.java
       ...
    > <package name>
       > <Class>.java
       ...
```

Comment: Попробовал создать новый проект - он вообще не запускается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Я удалил лишний Software (`Android` и `Maven`), и все заработало:

```
Help >> Install New Software >> What is already installed
```